# Mako: NameError when using global variable

Tags: python, mako

The following example from the [Mako docs](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/rel_0_6/defs.html#defs-within-defs) actually doesn't work:

```
<%
    x = 12
%>
<%def name="outer()">
    <%
        y = 15
    %>
    <%def name="inner()">
        inner, x is ${x}, y is ${y}
    </%def>

    outer, x is ${x}, y is ${y}
</%def>
```

When I add `<%self:outer />` below to call to the def (nothing else is in the file), the page will error out and my apache log says

```
[Sun Dec 02 13:25:08 2012] [error] [client 89.247.172.1]   File "/tmp/mako_template_cache/index.html.mako.py", line 82, in render_outer
[Sun Dec 02 13:25:08 2012] [error] [client 89.247.172.1]     __M_writer(str(x))
[Sun Dec 02 13:25:08 2012] [error] [client 89.247.172.1]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 195, in __str__
[Sun Dec 02 13:25:08 2012] [error] [client 89.247.172.1]     raise NameError("Undefined")
[Sun Dec 02 13:25:08 2012] [error] [client 89.247.172.1] NameError: Undefined
```

What could I be doing wrong? I have Mako 0.7.0 from Debian for which it should work.

Answer (score 1):

the template as given in the docs doesn't actually do anything since it's not even calling `inner()` or `outer()`.   The usage the docs are describing is local function calls:

```
from mako.template import Template

print Template("""
<%
    x = 12
%>
<%def name="outer()">
    <%
        y = 15
    %>
    <%def name="inner()">
        inner, x is ${x}, y is ${y}
    </%def>

    outer, x is ${x}, y is ${y}

    ${inner()}
</%def>

${outer()}

""").render()
```

output:

```
outer, x is 12, y is 15


    inner, x is 12, y is 15
```

when you call `outer()` via the `self` namespace, that's called within a different variable scope so you don't get at "x" there.  "x" is defined within the "body" def, so only calling outer() as defined in the body() will have "x" present.

Comment: Thank you. So is there a tag aquivalent of `${outer()}`? (`<%outer/>` doesn't work, neither does `<%body:outer/>`). Or did you simply want to force function call syntax for global variable access?

Comment: yeah I had checked if I had added a syntax that guarantees local access and there's not right now.   The thing is, saying `<% a = 5 %>` in your template isn't "global", it's local to body().   A global is something you can get using a `<%! %>` block, so perhaps you're looking for [inheritable attributes](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/inheritance.html#inheritance-attr).

Comment: It would help if there was some remark on this at http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/defs.html as after reading *All defs, top level or not, have access to the current contextual namespace in exactly the same way their containing template does.* I had impression `x` would be visible, too.

Comment: right well, i guess the idea is that assignments to variables in a template aren't part of the context.  the context is the **kw that's passed to `template.render()`.